# What is an idiomatic way to define a function taking an iterator without consuming in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator

I've been working through the 2020 [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/) in Rust, trying to produce solutions involving fairly generic functions, which could (in theory) be reused elsewhere without having to worry too much about types. For day 2, the problem involves checking each line of a file to make sure that it is a string conforming to some given condition. My current approach is to define a function similar to the following:

```rust
fn filter_lines<'a>(lines: impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a str>) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    lines
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|line| verify_line(line))
        .collect()
}
```

Here, `verify_line` is just some function which takes an `&str` and produces a boolean depending on whether the line conforms to a certain specification.

The issue is that this function appears to necessarily consume the iterator. I've tried rewriting it as follows to use a reference to `lines`, and clone `lines` before operating on this, but this code won't compile:

```rust
fn filter_lines<'a>(lines: &impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a str>) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let lines = lines.clone();
    lines
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|line| verify_line(line))
        .collect()
}
```

The compiler produces the following error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*lines` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:40:5
   |
40 |     lines
   |     ^^^^^ move occurs because `*lines` has type `impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a str>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I think I understand why doing this isn't allowed, but I'm not sure how to idiomatically define a function such as `filter_lines` which won't consume the iterator. So, what would be a better way to implement this `filter_lines` function such that it can be called as follows?

```rust
let some_str: String = get_file_contents();
let lines = some_str.lines();
println!("Filtered lines: {:?}", filter_lines(&lines));
println!("All lines: {:?}", lines.collect::<Vec<&str>>());
```

Comment: I should have clarified: I've solved the problem posed in Advent of Code, I'm not trying to "cheat" on solving it, my question is just for my own interest :)

Comment: Note that the `IntoIterator` is designed explicitly to create iterators that are consumed. Compare the `into_iter()` and `iter()` methods, for example on Vec. `iter()` doesn't consume the input, but is actually defined by the generic slice type. This is due to the fact that if you don't consume an iterator, you merely reference it, therefore it needs an owner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue for me is that this function appears to necessarily consume the iterator.

That's going to happen in every case, because that's what `IntoIterator` does. So if you take an `IntoIterator` input, it's up to the *caller* to set it up correctly e.g. Vec has `impl IntoIterator for Vec<T>` and `impl IntoIterator for &[T]`, so the caller can pass in `&v` — though that requires some adaptation anyway as the `IntoIterator` for `&[T]` yields `Iterator<Item=&T>`, so here it's an `Iterator<Item=&&str>` which wouldn't work.

But since every `Iterator` also implements `IntoIterator` as well that's not really an issue: the caller can just do some adaptation. Anyway my point is the function works as-is, it's the caller which needs changes.

Now as to the specific snippet:

```rust
let some_str: String = get_file_contents();
let lines = some_str.lines();
println!("Filtered lines: {:?}", filter_lines(&lines));
println!("All lines: {:?}", lines.collect::<Vec<&str>>());
```

*that* can not work, because `Lines` *is an `Iterator`* it will be consumed by any iteration: Rust iterators are not "replayable", it's only the "iterables" which *may* be. But it also doesn't really make much sense to try and reuse `lines()`, what would that even do?

- it could redo the entire thing, but then just call `some_str.lines()` twice and create two iterators in parallel
- or it could memoise the entire thing, but then just `collect()` the `Lines` upfront and iterate on the subsequent `Vec` however you need, that's basically what you're expecting, and since you're collecting to a vec anyway to print all the lines you might as well do that first:

  ```
  let some_str: String = String::from("foo\nbar\nbaz");
  let lines = some_str.lines().collect::<Vec<_>>();
  // Vec<&str> -> Iterator<Item=&&str> -> Iterator<Item=&str>
  println!("Filtered lines: {:?}", filter_lines(lines.iter().map(|s| *s)));
  println!("All lines: {:?}", lines);
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the insightful answer, I really appreciate it! That makes total sense, I think my intuition about iterators was a bit off beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Not saying this is the idiomatic way to do this, but in your snippet, you are actually cloning the reference because of which it doesn't work.

```rust
fn filter_lines<'a>(lines: &impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a str>) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    // Here you are creating a clone of the reference, not iterator
    let lines = lines.clone();
    lines
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|line| verify_line(line))
        .collect()
}
```

To clone the iterator, you need to impose a trait bound for `Clone` as well:

```rust
fn filter_lines<'a>(lines: &(impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a str> + Clone)) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let lines = lines.clone();
    lines
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|line| verify_line(line))
        .collect()
}
```

Because [Lines implements Clone](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Lines.html#impl-Clone) as well, this will work.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b7d5b9e513cbf3b298f54578a3f46e17)

Comment: Ah, thank you! I'm going to change my approach to this problem a little because of Masklinn's answer, but this is definitely helpful in understanding the error the compiler raised :) Do you know why auto-dereferencing doesn't apply here?

Comment: @user14749127, `lines.clone()` will work here as well as long as you specify bounds for `Clone`. Both reference and your iterator implement `Clone`. In second case when you specified bound for `Clone`, due to type inference rust came to the conclusion you mean iterator's clone. But in first case, as your iterator didn't have any `clone()` method so it sticked with reference's clone.